# Display video using QImage in the same window?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, ros

I am trying to display the video taken by a simulator. I am implementing the QT code in ROS by including its header file. My code is running. 
PROBLEM:: Everytime the new window is opened to display the frame. I have kept cvWaitKey(10000) so that new windows will come after a time delay. But the updated frames should come inside the same window. Pls suggest how can i do it?? My code is following:

```
   void imageCallback( const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg) //const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr&
{   
    imagePublisher.publish (cv_ptr->toImageMsg());                                                      

    QImage temp(&(msg->data[0]), msg->width, msg->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    QImage image;
    image=temp;
    // QT Layout with button and image  

    static QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    static QLabel *imageLabel= new QLabel;
    static QPushButton* quitButton= new QPushButton("Quit"); 
    static QPushButton* exitButton= new QPushButton("Exit Image");  
    QVBoxLayout* layout= new QVBoxLayout;


    imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    layout->addWidget(imageLabel);
    layout->addWidget(exitButton);      
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);  

    window->setLayout(layout);
    QObject::connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),window, SLOT(close()));  // Adding Buttons
    QObject::connect(exitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),imageLabel, SLOT(close()));

    window->show();
    cvWaitKey(1);


}
```

int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {

```
   ros::init(argc, argv, "imageSelectNode");
   ros::NodeHandle n("~");




   image_transport::ImageTransport it(n);    
   image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/camera/image_raw",1, imageCallback);

   imagePublisher = it.advertise("imagePublisherTopic", 1);     //Publish the image in 'imagePublisherTopic' node



QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ros::spin();
 return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why using a temporary 'image' variable?

Answer (score 2):

A new window is opened, because you create a new `QLabel` on each frame. What you need is - one `QLabel`, which pixmap you should change. The simplest way to do that is to make your `imageLabel` static:

```
static QLabel *imageLabel = new QLabel;
```

**Update**:

If you want to do some manipulations to this label once (like adding it to a layout), you could do something like this:

```
QLabel * createLabel()
{
    QLabel *l = new QLabel;
    layout->addWidget(l);
    return l;
}

...

static QLabel *imageLabel = createLabel();
```

**Update 4**:

```
QLabel * createLabel()
{
    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QLabel *imageLabel= new QLabel;
    QPushButton* quitButton= new QPushButton("Quit"); 
    QPushButton* exitButton= new QPushButton("Exit Image");  
    QVBoxLayout* layout= new QVBoxLayout;

    layout->addWidget(imageLabel);
    layout->addWidget(exitButton);      
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);  

    window->setLayout(layout);
    QObject::connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),window, SLOT(close()));
    QObject::connect(exitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),imageLabel, SLOT(close()));

    window->show();
    return imageLabel;
}

void imageCallback( const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
    imagePublisher.publish (cv_ptr->toImageMsg());

    QImage temp(&(msg->data[0]), msg->width, msg->height, QImage::Format_RGB888);

    QImage image;
    image = temp;

    static QLabel *imageLabel = createLabel();
    imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    cvWaitKey(1);
}
```

Comment: it worked but i want to add this QLabel into my Layout. So, by declaring the QLabel as Static, i am continously getting an error message "trying to change the layout which already have a previously set layout"......although the program is giving me the required functionality but i am getting continouly this message in my Terminal window. Pls suggest ...

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated by code. kindly check once. The problem is that i am calling my callback function from the Main() program when i subscribe the camera image. I do not understand how do i define the callback() in another class . Kindly help

Comment: Sorry i did not understand how to do ...label a member of class and ""create it in a window class's constructor""

Comment: thanks, i think that u have written the code for QT creator files. But i am not writting the code in QT. I am wrtting the code for a ROS node and there i am using some QT stuff. Kindly check my code..i am getting this error "QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget "", which already has a layout
"

Comment: This one I answered in the first update. Use `static QLabel *imageLabel = createLabel();` construction and move all gui creating there. Nevertheless, this code is quite ugly without using Qt's object paradigm.

Comment: i have used  QLabel *imageLabel = createLabel(layout); and QLabel* createLabel(&layout){...}. But still i am getting the same error "QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QWidget "", which already has a layout"